# Adding Spell Check wysiwyg editor

Tags: jquery, iframe, wysiwyg, spell-checking, spelling

This works great for spell checking textaras but I want to attach it to a wysiwyg editor

Tried adding the iframe id with no luck

```
< textarea name="TextArea1" id="futured" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
< a href="#check-textarea" id="check-textarea">check</a>

<script type="text/javascript">


    // check the spelling on a textarea
    $("#check-textarea").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".loading").show();

        $("#futured")
        .spellchecker({
            lang: "en",
            engine: "google",
            suggestBoxPosition: "above"
        })
        .spellchecker("check", function(result){
            $(".loading").hide();
            if (result) {
                alert('There are no incorrectly spelt words.');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Its from leigeber.com but I can't seem to find the name

Comment: @rickyduck Here is the example http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinyeditor/

Comment: I should say I know there are much better editors out their. But I want to stay with this one for now